What part of the deuterocanonical books might be objectionable to Jews?
Regarding the Old Testament canon, Protestants follow the Jewish canon based on the assumption that this is the canon accepted by Jews before the coming of Christ. However, the historical evidence that the canon of the Hebrew Bible was decided before Christ is far from conclusive. There are some ancient claims (as can be found in Justin Martyr for example) that the Jews altered their OT in order to elide the parts that might look Christian, and I have heard some Catholics say that the deuterocanonical books were left out of the Jewish canon for the same reason.
I guess I'm a little skeptical that this makes sense. Is there anything in any of the deuterocanonical books that would be objectionable to Jews?
To be clear, I am asking specifically about the contents of the books. The well-established fact of their late authorship (relative to the protocanon) and the fact that many of them were not composed in Hebrew were probably also factors influencing the Jews' decision not to canonize the Apocrypha. However, I am wondering whether there are additional reasons related to what the books actually say. I don't need an example from each of the deuterocanonical books, I would be satisfied by just one or two examples of statements from them which Jews would disagree with but not Christians would not.

There's quite well established theory that the Jews stopped using the Septuagint because of Christians (see here).  Possibly around the same time that they firmed up their Hebrew Bible canon at the Council of Jamnia.

Yes, but that doesn't explain why they did not use books such as Sirach and 1st Maccabees which were originally Hebrew

That's true.  So there may be other reasons.  It's quite plausible that there are several reasons.

Yes, I am sure there are several reasons. I have updated the question to clarify that I am wondering whether any of those reasons are that the contents of the books seem distinctively Christian.

It's a very good question. Why is it on Christianity and not http://judaism.stackexchange.com? You're asking why don't Jews accept a collection of books as scripture, why would this be answerable by Christian experts instead of Jews?

I thought about it, but I decided to post here for two reasons: first, the claim is made by Christians (so I'm wondering why they believe it) and second, I guess that Christians are more likely to have actually read the books in question.


the canon of the Hebrew Bible was decided before Christ is far from conclusive

Consider what Jesus said in Luke 11:49–51:

49 Therefore also said the wisdom of God, I will send them prophets and apostles, and some of them they shall slay and persecute:
50 That the blood of all the prophets, which was shed from the foundation of the world, may be required of this generation;
51 From the blood of Abel unto the blood of Zacharias, which perished between the altar and the temple: verily I say unto you, It shall be required of this generation.

These two deaths are recorded in Genesis 4:8:

And Cain talked with Abel his brother: and it came to pass, when they were in the field, that Cain rose up against Abel his brother, and slew him.

and 2 Chronicles 24:20–21:

20 And the Spirit of God came upon Zechariah the son of Jehoiada the priest, which stood above the people, and said unto them, Thus saith God, Why transgress ye the commandments of the LORD, that ye cannot prosper? because ye have forsaken the LORD, he hath also forsaken you.
21 And they conspired against him, and stoned him with stones at the commandment of the king in the court of the house of the LORD.

In the Tanakh (Hebrew Bible), the first book is Genesis, and the last book is  Chronicles.
Jesus was referring to these deaths in the first and last books of the Jewish canon.
It's hard to argue that the canon also included any of the deuterocanonical books at that time.

What part of the deuterocanonical books might be objectionable to Jews?

If these writings were rejected because they contain objectionable material, that material was objectionable before Christianity.

Yes, I have heard this argument before many times. It's OK but it's not airtight. I'm wondering what in particular in the contents of the apocryphal books was considered objectionable.
